# How can I scan double-sided postcards that cannot bend?

Tags: scanning, scanner

Note to editor: sorry about my horrible English but you took out parts of my question too. The scanner can not have rollers.

I am trying to take scans, also known as photos, of post cards. I figure  the best way is to use a scanner. At work we have a $5,000 dollar Xerox (all in one) that makes a scan of both sides at once.

My budget is a lot lower, around $200.00 is what I am shooting for. My question is: Is there a scanner that can scan both sides at once? or scan one side and save it as a file, then scan the other side and save it as a file and save it as a JPEG or PDF?  One file or two does not matter. I have hundreds of postcards. I just want to save time by avoiding flipping.

BONUS. If you can type in a name and it names it to filewhatever1 then filewhatever2 etc.. while I'm scanning a pile of documents that would be a plus.

NOTE: I am now realizing how hard it is to find something like this. So I guess my next question is there even anything on the market like this? price doesn't matter as much now.

Comment: Hum. personallly I think you are aiming at the wrong direction. I think any new scanner theese days will deliver good quality on the scan. But look for one which has a built in software that **removes the screening** on the print. You won't find any scanner that scan both sides at once without bending the paper.

Comment: If you have a lot of scanning to do, look for two aditional things. A fast scanner, and one that detects automaticly which area of the scanner bead has actually something on it. Some Auto-crop feature.

Comment: it doesn't have to scan both sides at once. It could scan the other side first then the side second.. I was just looking to save a bunch of time

Comment: You need to look for saving time on other parts of the process. Mainly, the preview, the scanning itself, and the descreening. You probably need a batch action on Photoshop to descreen, not to do it during the scann.

Comment: the photoshop I already have figured out. My issue is with pulling it out putting it back in fliping i upside down and realigning it.

Comment: maybe I might be better off with some sort of book scanner?

Comment: IME sequential filenames have been a routine option in scanner software for years. Scanning multiple pages to a single file has become routine recently. As you want to do both, you may have a couple of extra clicks but that's all. So the usual advice to *choose a scanner based on bit depth and **optical** resolution* (your image editor can interpolate better than your scanner) applies.

Comment: Do you have a DSLR?  If yes, how about one of [these](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=qlgFV9qyGPPS8Ae-zp6oBg&gws_rd=ssl#q=dslr+copy+stand&newwindow=1&tbm=shop) with a suitable macro lens, strobe, etc.

Comment: @dav1dsm1th yes I do

Answer (score 2):

I've successfully scanned batches of postcards, photos, and even entire thick old photo album pages with a 600dpi [Canon P-208ii document scanner](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/products/details/scanners/document-scanner/imageformula-p-208). It scans both sides at once, outputs to a range of formats including JPG and PDF, can do automatic image corrections and alignment on the fly, and works pretty fast. Pricewise, it's currently available from online retailers for less than $200. Just my personal experience, not affiliated with Canon in any way.

Comment: 600dpi is a little bit on the low resolution end of the scale.

Comment: @MichaelClark That's true in absolute terms, but how much print resolution is there in a postcard anyway to begin with? I'd argue that with a souvenir-kiosk type of commercial postcard, one would be hard pressed to find even 300dpi worth of resolved detail. The OP did not state anything about the age and quality of his postcards, but in my own experience with vintage postcards from the 1970/80s, I couldn't find any more detail with a loupe than what showed up in the 600dpi scan.

Comment: The person who edited my horrible english took this part out. ( It can not have rollers) Some of the items are very delicate. And we learned this hard way.

Comment: @user50277 So much for improving other peoples questions  … that obviously rules out the Canon then.

Comment: haha it happens :) A for effort.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the US$89 Pro version of [VueScan](http://www.hamrick.com) with my Epson Perfection flatbed scanner to scan multipage documents one side at a time (without a document feeder) and output the results as a multipage pdf file. This software supports an extensive list of scanners.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your boss/manager at work if you can use the Xerox scanner after work.

It is the right tool for the job.

If you have some money pool at work for coffee or the Christmas staff party for example, make a generous donation to that. Or ask if you can provide some other form of compensation.

Comment: I wold have a lot of stuff to haul. If it comes to that I would probably just buy a broken if I can.